# Left and right homotopies have the same equivalence relations

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f, g \colon A \longrightarrow X$ be continuous functions of topological spaces. We say that $f,g$ are left-homotopic if there exists a continuous map $H \colon A \times I \longrightarrow X$ such that $H(a, 0) = f(a) $ and $H(a,1)  = g(a) $. We say that $f,g$ are right-homotopic if there exists a continuous map $K \colon A \longrightarrow X^I$ where $X^I = \mathsf{Top}(I, X)$ is the space of continuous maps with the compact-open topology, such that $K(a)(0) = f(a)$ and $K(a)(1) = g(a)$. In $X^I$ a subbase for the topology is given by the collection of subsets $V(K, U) \subseteq X^I$ where $K \subseteq I$ is compact, $U \subseteq X$ is open and
$$
V(K, U) = \left\{ \lambda \in X^I \vert  \ \lambda( K) \subseteq U\right\}.
$$

I am trying to show that the equivalence classes for left and right homotopy are equivalent. I have been able to show left $\implies$ right: Given a left homotopy $H \colon A \times I \longrightarrow X$ define $K \colon A \longrightarrow X^I$ by $K(a)(t) = H(a,t)$. Choose $\tilde K \subseteq I$ compact and $U \subseteq X$ open. Then

$$
K^{-1}  ( V (\tilde K, U ) ) = \displaystyle\bigcap_{t \in \tilde K} (H i_t )^{-1} (U)
$$
where $\iota_t \colon A \longrightarrow A \times I$ is the map $a \mapsto (a,t)$. It is sufficient to check inverse images of the subbase.

Now given right homotopy $K \colon A \longrightarrow X^I$ define $H \colon A \times I \longrightarrow X$ by $H(a,t) = K(a)(t)$. I presume this is the correct function. How do I show it is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main result you need is that if $A,Y,X$ are topological spaces and the space $X^Y$ of continuous functions $Y \to X$ is given the compact open topology then the exponential map

$$e: X^{A \times Y}  \to (X^Y)^A$$

which sends $f: A \times Y \to X $ to the function which on $a \in A$ has value the function $y \mapsto f(a,y)$, this map $e$ is well defined and is a bijection if $Y$ is locally compact, i.e. each point of $Y$ has a base of compact neighbourhoods. The case you are interested in is when  $Y=I$, the unit interval, which is Hausdorff and locally compact.

For more information on this sort of question see the wiki entry on [convenient categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces) and also, to plug my account, Section 5.9 of [Topology and Groupoids](Http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html). In category theory, this discussion is about the notion of *cartesian closed categories*.

Lawvere has given an intuitive description of these ideas. One sees $X^Y$ as a kind of phase space of positions of $y \in Y$ in terms of $X$. Then $(X^Y)^I$ is the space of paths in the phase space. On the other hand, $(X^I)^Y$ is a phase space of paths.

Later: Just to answer Paul's question on the continuity of $e$; this question is easier to answer if one knows **exactly** what is $(X^Y)^A$. I published  the answer in my first two  papers, available from my publication list.  There is a natural topology on the set product $A \times Y$ giving a space $A \times_S Y$: it takes the usual product topology and the takes the final topology with respect to all subsets of the form $\{a\} \times Y, A \times C$ where $ a \in A$ and $C$ is compact in $Y$. (This all works in the Hausdorff case. There is a modification for the non Hausdorff case.) This product is associative. Then one finds that the natural map

$$e_S: X^{A \times_S Y}  \to (X^Y)^A$$

is a **bijection**! One can also use the associativity to prove this is a homeomorphism. In modern terminology, we can make the category $Top$ of spaces and continuous maps into a monoidal closed category. Of course this monoidal structure is not symmetric. Too bad! The identity  map $ A \times_S Y \to A \times Y$ is continuous, so we get an embedding $X^{A \times Y} \to X^{A \times_S Y}$, which proves the continuity of $e$ without getting ones hands dirty!

With regard to the non Hausdorff case, this is dealt with in a paper on Convenient Categories by Booth and Tillotson in the Pacific J. Math. 1980. One replaces compact subsets of a space $Z$ by test maps from a compact Hausdorff space to $Z$, as in Section 5.9 of T&G.

The second paper on "Function spaces and product topologies" (1964) gives stronger results than were published in 1968 by someone else.

Comment: Just to be clear, is that map $e$ continuous given those hypotheses?